# how do I generate pages dynamically by a JSON file

Tags: ruby, middleman

I need to create hundreds of static **product** html pages by a data JSON file

First, I will load all the products information from **data.json**

Then, load it into **product-page** template,

Finally, apply it into **layout** template

How could I finish it in **middleman**

Or if I can generate all the product static pages with **product-page** by any   exsiting gem

## data.json

````
```json
[
  {
    product_name: "~~"
    product_images_link: "~~"
    product_price: "~~"
    product_description: "~~"
  },
  {
    product_name: "~~"
    product_images_link: "~~"
    product_price: "~~"
    product_description: "~~"
  }
]

```
````

## layout

```
%html
  %head
    %link{:href => "/stylesheets/bootstrap.css", :rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css"}/
  %body.overview
    = yield
    %script{:src => "/javascripts/overview.js"}
```

## product-page

```
.head
  .product_info
    %h1= product_name
    %h1= product_price
    = product_description
  .image
    %img{:alt => "", :src => "#{product_images_link}"}/
```

Comment: If you need to generate text from a template, have you considered trying [erb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) ?

Comment: hi @floum is there any simple tutorial or link about erb to generate?

Comment: check this excellent guide : http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Haml, you can do it like this http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html:

```
class SomeClass
  def generate_product_files
    products.each do |product|
      save_product_as_html(product)
    end
  end

  private

  def save_product_as_html(product)
    html = product_template_engine.render(
      Object.new,
      product_name:        product.fetch(:name),
      product_price:       product.fetch(:price),
      product_description: product.fetch(:description),
      product_images_link: product.fetch(:product_images_link)
    )

    file_path = "products/product-#{ product.fetch(:id) }"

    File.open(file_path, 'w') do |file|
      file.puts(html)
    end
  end

  def product_template_engine
    @product_template_engine ||= Haml::Engine.new(File.read('some_template.html.haml'))
  end
end
```